# Multi-Threading and opening files in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, file, video-capture

I want 2 threads to open 1 file, then doing some processes. 
in details, my file is .avi video, and im extracting frames from the file.
i'm extracting odd numbered frames with 1 thread, and even numbered frames with the other thread.

That's the important part of my code:

```
Capture video = new Capture("c:\\5.avi");
Image<Bgr, Byte> Imageframe;
Imageframe = video.QueryFrame();
```

However, when the second thread work, and open the same file ( 5.avi ), or even another file
it gives me this message (unable to create capture from c:\5.avi)
please advise me on what to do, im new to the threading programming

Thanks.

Comment: You must apply mutual exclusion for this to ensure that just one thread accessing shared resource, that is in your cause video variable.

Comment: what do you mean mutual exclusion ?

Comment: In this case try to learn something in context of using multithreading in some application. You can start from Wikipedia:)

Comment: When two threads want to access a shared resource, they typically cannot do so simultaneously. If one has it, the other may not, hence the term mutual exclusivity.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having one thread (only) read the file, and feeding two worker threads with the frames. Not necessarily the only way, but cleaner code will result.

Comment: 2 threads reading in the same time is important to me for speeding the process

Comment: Disk I/O is the bottleneck for the read, not CPU. I repeat; Have one thread read the file, and farm out the processing to two worker threads.

Comment: Actually, even once you manage to get two threads cooperating to read the file, i will likely be slower than my proposal; during the time it takes to context-switch the next disk block has probably rotated out from under the disk read head.

Comment: Listen to @PieterGeerkens - I would be absolutely amazed if two threads could read alternate chunks from one file faster than one thread could read sequential data into two Image objects and queue them off to a processing pool.

Comment: ..especially if the file was on a networked disk, or other variable-latency device with dubious locking functionality.

Comment: Agree with @PieterGeerkens - I respectfully suggest you're forgetting that the value of 2 threads is going to be lost because your going to be disk-bound, not thread bound.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can only have a single 'Capture' process running.

Comment: but i want to run 2 at a time !

Comment: if internally, there is some checking to ensure only a single Capture process runs, there is little you can do about it.

Comment: like what ? please advise me